# Find specific word in reg ex along with special character

Tags: c#, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-greedy, boost-regex

```
string emailBody = " holla holla testing is for NewFinancial History:\"xyz\"  dsd  NewFinancial History:\"abc\"  NewEBTDI$:\"abc\"  dsds  ";

   emailBody = string.Join(" ", Regex.Split(emailBody.Trim(), @"(?:\r\n|\n|\r)"));
                var keys = Regex.Matches(emailBody, @"\bNew\B(.+?):", RegexOptions.Singleline).OfType<Match>().Select(m => m.Groups[0].Value.Replace(":", "")).Distinct().ToArray();
                foreach (string key in keys)
                {
                    List<string> valueList = new List<string>();
                    string regex = "" + key + ":" + "\"(?<" + GetCleanKey(key) + ">[^\"]*)\"";

                    var matches = Regex.Matches(emailBody, regex, RegexOptions.Singleline);
                    foreach (Match match in matches)
                    {
                        if (match.Success)
                        {
                            string value = match.Groups[GetCleanKey(key)].Value;
                            if (!valueList.Contains(value.Trim()))
                            {
                                valueList.Add(value.Trim());
                            }
                        }
                    }

 public string GetCleanKey(string key)
        {
            return key.Replace(" ", "").Replace("-", "").Replace("#", "").Replace("$", "").Replace("*", "").Replace("!", "").Replace("@", "")
                .Replace("%", "").Replace("^", "").Replace("&", "").Replace("(", "").Replace(")", "").Replace("[", "").Replace("]", "").Replace("?", "")
                .Replace("<", "").Replace(">", "").Replace("'", "").Replace(";", "").Replace("/", "").Replace("\"", "").Replace("+", "").Replace("~", "").Replace("`", "")
                .Replace("{", "").Replace("}", "").Replace("+", "").Replace("|", "");
        }
```

In my above code I am trying to get the value next to `NewEBTDI$:` which is `"abc"`.

When I include `$` sign in the pattern, it doesn't search the value next to field name.

If the `$` is removed and one just specifies `NewEBTDI` then it searches the values.

I want to search the value along with the `$` sign.

Comment: Please arrange your code properly. It's not readable.

Comment: "$" has a special meaning in Regex.  Escape it with a \.  But in your case you will have to do a String.Replace() method because your regex is generated .  You might have other special character as well...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The right way of handling characters that have a special meaning in regex, but must be searched as is, is to escape them. You can do this with `Regex.Escape`. In your case it is the `$` sign, which means *end of line* in regex, if not escaped.

```
string regex = "" + Regex.Escape(key) + ":" + "\"(?<" + Regex.Escape(GetCleanKey(key))
               + ">[^\"]*)\"";
```

or

```
string regex = String.Format("{0}:\"(?<{1}>[^\"]*)\"",
                             Regex.Escape(key),
                             Regex.Escape(GetCleanKey(key)));
```

or with VS 2015, using string interpolation:

```
string regex = $"{Regex.Escape(key)}:\"(?<{Regex.Escape(GetCleanKey(key))}>[^\"]*)\"";
```

*(It does look better than that in reality, because the C# editor colors the string parts and the embedded C# expressions differently.)*

Comment: I did not know about Regex.Escape!

Answer (score 1):

It is unclear what is the ultimate goal, but the `$` in a pattern is a pattern escape which means either the end of the line, or the end of the buffer depending if `MultiLine` is set or not.

Why not just capture the text before the `:` into a named capture? Then extract the quoted operation value such as:

```
var data = "...is for NewFinancial History:\"xyz\"  dsd  NewFinancial History:\"abc\"  NewEBTDI$:\"abc\"  dsds";

var pattern = @"
(?<New>New[^:]+)      # Capture all items after `New` that is *not* (`^`) a `:`, one or more.
:                     # actual `:`
\x22                  # actual quote character begin anchor
(?<InQuotes>[^\x22]+) # text that is not a quote, one or more
\x22                  # actual quote ending anchor
";

// IgnorePatternWhitespace allows us to comment the pattern. Does not affect processing.
Regex.Matches(data, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace | RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture)
     .OfType<Match>()
     .Select(mt => new
     {
         NewText = mt.Groups["New"].Value,
         Text = mt.Groups["InQuotes"].Value
     });
```

**Result**

[image]

Note I use the hex escape `\x22` instead of escaping the `\"` in the pattern for easier working with it. For it circumvents the C# compiler prematurely escaping a pattern escapes which needs to remain intact.